# Dropdown not updating after filling from JSON file

Tags: javascript, select

I have a dropdown (select) that on page load gets emptied and populated from a JSON file based on selection from another dropdown. This is functioning. However, when I try to access the dropdown programmatically to set the selected item, it doesn't work. When I try to verify that the items have populated, it always shows a "length" of 2 even though there may be 10 items visible in the browser.

Here is the code I'm using to load the dropdown:

```
let worksitelist = $('#element_14'); //element ID for the select
$.getJSON(lxw, function(data) { //lxw is the path to the JSON file
  worksitelist.empty();
  worksitelist.prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
  $.each(data, function(key, entry) {
    if (mylocal != entry.local) {
      return true;
    } else {
      worksitelist.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.worksite).text(entry.worksite));
    }
  })
});
```

If I come along after this and try the code below, it is as if nothing was loaded into the dropdown:

```
var d=document.getElementById('element_14'); //element ID for the select
var t=document.getElementById('element_99'); //element ID for the input that hold the text value to set in the select
var w=t.value;  

for (var i = 0; i < d.options.length; i++) {
    if (d.options[i].text === w) {
        d.selectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure the code is good. Somewhere I'm missing a piece of the puzzle so the dropdown (d) shows as only having 2 items. I'm pulling my hair out on this one so any help would be so very much appreciated!

I've tried using JS and JQuery, but it all comes back to the fact that even though I've "appended" items from the JSON file into the select, and the items appear in the select in the browser, when I try to read the values of the select programmatically, they aren't there. I've tried using change commands in an attempt to update the select, but they don't seem to do anything...

Comment: FWIW, to select you should be able to just use `$("#element_14").val(t.value)`. However, is the code that you are using to get the length of the drop down in another function or just randomly on the page? If it just happens to be sitting BELOW your getJSON, then its possible the code is being ran below the data is loaded. If its in a function then that is a different story.

Comment: Are you actually running the second code block after the `getJSON` callback completes? Remember that `getJSON` is asynchronous.